# Error: Matrix dimension must agree (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, matrix

There is one part of the code (matlab), Where I'm getting this error

> Matrix dimension must agree

Below are the two implementation of same logic, But first one not working. What's the problem in first one can anybody tell

First implementation

```
f = 1/2 * (sum((theta .* X) - y).^2);
```

Second implementaion

```
hx = (theta' * X - y);
f = sum(hx.^2) * .5;
```

Above `X, y, theta` are column vectors of dimension `15 * 1` and the codes are implementation of

$J(\theta) = \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits{i}(\theta^T x^{(i)} - y^{(i)})^2$

Comment: This question cannot be answered without the dimensions of theta, X, and y.

Comment: They use different operations, `.*` vs `*`.

Comment: If they are all `15`-by-`1` then you could not have gotten a matrix dimension must agree error with your first implementation.

Comment: Your second one doesnt work or the first method ?

Comment: Your theta and X has dimension mismatch

Comment: Your second implementation is surely wrong because `theta' * X` is the same as `sum(theta.*X)` so your second implementation sums twice and broadcasts the difference between `y` and the *scalar* `theta' * X`

Comment: His second one is working and first one is not because his theta is  15x1 matrix and X is 1x15 so when you do theta.*X you get a dimension mismatch for the first one

Comment: @Umar I think second one is working but it will not produce correct result as it is not correctly computes result as formulas says.

Comment: Actually, I'm solving Stanford's UFLDL Deep learning Programming assignment.
http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/supervised/LinearRegression/

You can check the code here
https://www.dropbox.com/s/21uxkwloge154cl/stanford_dl_ex-master.rar?dl=0

head to the folder `ex1` and check the files 'linear_regression.m' 'ex1a_linreg.m'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `X, y` and theta are column vectors of dimension `15 * 1`,the correct implementation of your equation should be the first one and it should not give you any error [I checked with random `15*1` column vectors and it works fine].

The second code basically doesn't  implement your equation because what you are doing is: `theta' * X` [which is equivalent to `sum(theta.*X)`],subtracting y from the scalar sum to get `hx` and again summing up square of `hx`. I suggest you to recheck the dimensions of `theta`, `X` and `y`. From the code you uploaded, theta is `14*1`. So,since you also said you are not getting any error in the second code,perhaps `X` is `14*N` matrix and `y` is `1*N` row vector. In this case, you should know what to do with the equation and obviously you cannot use the first implementation as it is. Yet the second implementation is wrong.

Comment: I get it, Second one is the correct implementation. Here theta = 14*1, X =  14*400, y = 1*400